# AWS Codepipeline Step to do https call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-event-bridge

Just want to get some feedback here on the best possible way to do this.

Within my Codepipeline, I need to do an https call as a last step and I'll receive a payload and a 200 response back if all is good.

I'm trying to figure out what kind of stage to add for this? I was thinking of Lambda, but in my situation, I won't be able to put the Lambda in the same account. Is there any way I can just do an https call from one of the steps (event bridge isn't supported within codepipeline)?

Answer (score 0):

Calling lambda is best and cheapest approch.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html

How to call lambda in another account you can find detail in following link

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-s3-cross-account-function-invoke/

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned I was trying to avoid that because the cross account lambda call doesn't work very well. A bunch of permission changes and you actually need to export and import the json config for codepipeline to make it work.